# Disable Outlook (RPC over HTTPS) access in Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook, rpc

I know that I can enable/disable OWA, POP3 and IMAP on a per-user basis. However, I want one particular user to be able to connect *only* through OWA and not through Microsoft Outlook (which can access Exchange Server through RPC over HTTPS). Other users should be able to use MS Outlook.

So, basically, I want to lock down RPC over HTTPS access (which works fine at the moment) for one particular user.

Is it possible to do that? I'm using Exchange Server 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of access to mailbox also called MAPI access. Look at [that](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219050%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx) article on technet: it says you need add a value `MAPI§0§0§§§§§§` to user property `protocolSettings` via ADSIedit mmc console.